# There is an error in my calculator app(java.lang.NumberFormatException)

Tags: android

I'm getting this error in my code: `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.

- `m1` is for main string that contains the whole expression
- `s` is for second number if no operator other than division is present
- `f` is for first number if no operator other than division is present
- `f1` is for first number if operator other than division is also present
- `s1` is for second number if operator other than division is also present

Here is the code:

```
b12.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String s="";
        String f="";
        String f1="";
        String s1="";
        int z=m1.length();
        int pos,pos1;

        for(int i=0;i&lt;z;i++)
        {
            int m=m1.codePointAt(i);
            //Checking for division
            if(m==47)
            {

                // Loop to calculate second number
                for(int j=i+1;j&lt;z;j++)
                {
                    int d=m1.codePointAt(j);
                    if(d!=43||d!=45||d!=42||d!=47)
                    {
                        s+=m1;
                    }
                    else
                    { pos=j;
                        s1+=m1.substring(pos,z);
                        break;
                    }

                }


                // Loop to calculate first number
                for(int j=i-1;j&gt;=0;j--)
                {
                    int d=m1.codePointAt(j);
                    if(d!=43||d!=45||d!=42||d!=47)
                    {
                        f+=m1;
                    }
                    else
                    { pos1=j;
                        f1+=m1.substring(0,pos1);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                String rev=new StringBuffer(f).reverse().toString();
                float ans=Float.parseFloat(rev)/Float.parseFloat(s);

                String e=Float.toString(ans);

                if(f1==""&&s1=="")
                {
                    m1=""+e;
                }
                else
                {
                    m1=""+f1+e+s1;
                }
                z=m1.length();
                e1.setText(m1);
            }
        }


    }
});


}
```

Comment: Do you think it might be useful to tell us what the error is?

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException..

Comment: and on which line is thrown this exception?

Comment: This one:    float ans=Float.parseFloat(rev)/Float.parseFloat(s);

Comment: Either `rev` or `s` cannot represent a float.  Put a breakpoint on this line.  What values are they?

Answer (score 0):

Potential code which can throw `NumberFormatException` :

```
float ans=Float.parseFloat(rev)/Float.parseFloat(s);
```

Check if `rev` and `s` can resolve to a valid `float` value . Also you can do the following :

```
float ans=Float.parseFloat(rev.trim())/Float.parseFloat(s.trim());
```

which will remove the leading and trailing whitespaces, if any.

Also if possible , replace `StringBuffer` with [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).